# Challenge to regular members: Ask one non-how-to question this week

Tags: discussion

## Challenge

On account of [Should extremely basic 'how to do this in software X' questions be off-topic?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/should-extremely-basic-how-to-do-this-in-software-x-questions-be-off-topic) I am challenging all regular members to post non software related questions. Post one even.

Some suggestions - a topic that interests you, a topic you already know the answer to, something from Google Scholar, something relevant to current design trends, etc.

To make things better I'll bounty every non-software design question we get this week (until Thursday since I don't come on during the weekend and my office is closed Friday) from any regular member.

**Edit**

Its come to my attention there's a limit on Bounties so instead of everyone getting a bounty I'll do a 150pt Bounty to the 3 receiving the most attention. JohnB and Vincent will contribute their three bounties as well for a total of 9.

**Update**

With 3 people contributing for 9 bounties I'm capping it and will rollback further edits. I'm afraid it'll become regular members passing their rep to another regular member and we'll all end up the same. I'm less interested in rep-sharing and more interested in challenging all of you that are against software questions to pose better ones.

Comment: well i have to write a question then

Comment: Be aware that you can only start a bounty 48 hours after a question was asked. So, if you plan to get the bounties out before Friday, the questions have to be asked on Tuesday. Also, do you consider fonts software?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I can always offer it up on Monday if need be or JohnB and Vincent can take the extras. Fonts can get the bounty if its something interesting about their use, purpose or creation.

Comment: But why did you put so much emphasis on everything posted before Friday in the first place then?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft deadlines are important otherwise its just a discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok ive thought of a few design based questions and i will try to post one each Monday.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's about the bounties. If the questions are here we can get some great input without bounties.

My last round of bounties did *nothing* to garner new answers. Literally nothing.

I think just posing good questions is all that's really needed. Even if you answer them yourself.

Comment: Yeah i noticed this. But i didnt have anything to add. Besides i hoped somebody else would

Comment: Your logic is accurate but its built on the wrong assumption. I don't care about more Answers, I care about promoting the right kind of Questions.

Comment: Oh I agree. But Bounties lately haven't proven effective to me. Good questions are inherently valuable and tend to garner more views and answers with or without a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

So I've been on holiday for a week, just to come back and see Ryan has taken my idea and ran with it. That's great!

I'm all for it, and will do my best to ask some great questions.

I'm not really a fan of the bounty-idea, since it encourages answering for the sake of answering. I think a good question will get good answers, regardless of the 'what's in it for me'-feeling.