# Challenge to Members: Ask a non-how-to question, again!

Tags: discussion

In 2015 I did [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/challenge-to-regular-members-ask-one-non-how-to-question-this-week), coincidentally it was in March, so perfect to get it in today:

## Challenge

I am challenging all regular members to post non software how-to questions. Post one even.

Some suggestions - a topic that interests you, a topic you already know the answer to, something from Google Scholar, something relevant to current design trends, something topical, etc.

There's a limit on Bounties so instead of everyone getting a bounty I'll do a 150pt Bounty to the 3 receiving the most attention.

Please don't offer to contribute additional rep towards bounties, not trying to get rep passed around as much as trying to get some new, interesting questions.

Comment: [Done](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69293/why-is-moving-form-a-raster-editor-to-vector-editor-so-hard)!

Comment: Does this count: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69738/what-career-paths-does-a-graphic-design-degree-offer

Comment: What about "*[Why do most of the well known currency symbols have strikeouts in their symbols?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68399/46556)*"? :)

Comment: @elegent would you like the bounty for not enough attention or looking for something with authoritative reference?

Comment: IMHO the question attracted enough attention; so a official and credible reference would be interesting.

Comment: @elegent it has been bountified

Comment: Thank you very much for your support :) BTW, should the "[i font rendering problem](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/lowercase-i-looks-bad-in-header-3)" be posted on meta.SE ?